# opencv header file not included in cpp file android studio

Tags: android, c++, opencv, face-recognition

I am learning OpenCV library and want to develop a face recognization app, to do so I started with the integration of NDK with the android studio but I am stuck here in between.

I am able to successfully print the text message from cpp to activity in the Android framework

```
// Cpp Code
    extern "C"
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
    Java_com_detectface_tasolmyfacerec_utils_Opencv_toastCPPNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

        std::string hello = "OpenCV FaceDetection";

        return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
    }
//Java Code 
public native String toastCPPNative();
```

But when started adding the cpp supported headers they are not included and showing red highlight text, I want to include that files so that I can use the opencv algorithms

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             facedetection-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/facedetection-lib.cpp )


find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

I am providing the screenshots also
[image: look at the red highlighted text]

Comment: Obviously you have to add path to `OCV2\include` to include in build system ... for cmake is prolly `include_directories`

Comment: @Selvin: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I am using Cmakelists.txt to do so ,I am editing the question to add the CMakelists.txt

Comment: Feel free to read cmake documetation not mention that googling for "opencv2 android Cmake" will return enough information

Comment: well, I have already done that and not succeeded that's why I posted the question here, anyways thanks.